# How to get the search results in real time?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm a building a website like **[udemy.com](https://www.udemy.com/)**. On the front page there is search bar for the users to search for the courses they want to enroll in.

How to get it done to show the results if the users inputs something?

I know that ajax will be used in this scenario. But anyone got the working solution or the better implementation?

I hope i'm clear with my question.

Comment: _"But anyone got the working solution or the better implementation?"_ SO doesn't provide the working solution, give it a try yourself.

Comment: how? that's what i asked here!

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial place, you're not the first to want a real time search function, google for a tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_? Currently your question reads "I am building a website like this other website, i want my website to do this. Can someone do it for me?". Search for "autocomplete" on google, mess around with examples, try and make it do what you're trying to do, if you get stuck then come back and ask a question about the problems you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@arosh, are you looking for something like this: [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: Yeah, somewhat like this. But i want to fetch the list from my database instead of hard coding it to jquery array. Do you know how to do so?

Comment: Alright, check this then...this has autocomplete+php+mysql [link](http://www.wowww.nl/2014/02/01/jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-php-mysql/)